ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 'number' failed.(missing: /_next/static/chunks/715-98a54eede6c88c3f.js)
Help please!
Use next ^14.2.3
Sometimes i get Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information). It is very hard to repeat, but if you refresh the page many times it may appear.
In console:
ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 715 failed.(missing: /_next/static/chunks/715-98a54eede6c88c3f.js)
Config Next:
const nextConfig = {
  output: "standalone",
  env: {
    title: "SiteTitle",
    description: "SiteDescription"
  },
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [{ hostname: "*" }],
  },
  poweredByHeader: false,
  reactStrictMode: false,
}

Tried different versions of nextjs. I tried to remove caching on js files. I tried adding to the config:
async headers() {
  return [
    {
      source: '/',
      headers: [
        {
          key: 'Cache-Control',
          value: 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate',
        },
      ],
    }
  ]
}

